# histogram for multiple variables in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, histogram, overlap

I want to make a histogram for multiple variables. 
I used the following code :

```
set.seed(2)
dataOne <- runif(10)
dataTwo  <- runif(10)
dataThree <- runif(10)
one <-  hist(dataOne, plot=FALSE)
two  <-  hist(dataTwo, plot=FALSE)
three  <- hist(dataThree, plot=FALSE)
plot(one, xlab="Beta Values", ylab="Frequency",
     labels=TRUE, col="blue", xlim=c(0,1))
plot(two, col='green', add=TRUE)
plot(three, col='red', add=TRUE)
```

But the problem is that they *cover* each other, as shown below.

I just want them to be added to each other (showing the bars over each other) i.e. not overlapping/ not covering each other.
How can I do this ?

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to stackoverflow! As you are new on SO, please take some time to read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [how to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [minimal, reproducible data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. Please also clarify the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R histogram with multiple populations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612805/r-histogram-with-multiple-populations)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last three lines by:

```
plot(One, xlab = "Beta Values", ylab = "Frequency", col = "blue")
points(Two, col = 'green')
points(Three, col = 'red')
```

The first time you need to call `plot`. But the next time you call plot it will start a new plot which means you lose the first data. Instead you want to add more data to it either with scatter chart using `points`, or with a line chart using `lines`.

Comment: Although it is not entirely clear in OP what the final plot should look like, it was not asked for `points` or `lines`.

Comment: @Henrik My understanding is that plot gives a scatter plot by default, and points also gives a scatter plot. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't interpret the OP as the desired result is a scatterplot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are looking for here.

One approach is to place the plots in separate plotting spaces:

```
par("mfcol"=c(3, 1))
hist(dataOne, col="blue")
hist(dataTwo, col="green")
hist(dataThree, col="red") 
par("mfcol"=c(1, 1))
```

Is this what you're after?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need. If it's not, let me know and I'll sort it out.

```
# Configuración inicial
set.seed(2)
dataOne <- runif(100)
dataTwo <- runif(100)
dataThree <- runif(100)

# Crear histogramas sin graficar
one <- hist(dataOne, plot=FALSE)
two <- hist(dataTwo, plot=FALSE)
three <- hist(dataThree, plot=FALSE)

# Establecer límites para el eje x y eje y
xlim <- c(0, 1)
ylim <- c(0, max(one$counts, two$counts, three$counts) + 5)

# Graficar el primer histograma
plot(one, xlab="Valores Beta", ylab="Frecuencia", labels=TRUE, 
     col=rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.5), xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, 
     main="Histogramas Superpuestos", border="white")

# Agregar el segundo histograma
plot(two, col=rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha=0.5), add=TRUE, border="white")

# Agregar el tercer histograma
plot(three, col=rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.5), add=TRUE, border="white")

# Añadir una leyenda
legend("topright", legend=c("Data One", "Data Two", "Data Three"), 
       fill=c(rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.5), rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha=0.5), rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.5)))
```

[image: output]

Comment: It would be helpful if the comments in the code were translated to English, as that's the only explanation in the answer of what the code does.