# Stacked Histogram in R ggplot with 100+ qualitative colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, stackedbarseries

The data frame has many continuous numeric columns (e.g. `gr`) and a sample identifier - `wellseq`. There are many rows of data for each `wellseq`. In a data frame - there are 94 distinct levels of `wellseq` in 10227 rows. Header lines from data frame are:

```
 gr wellseq
 1 27.7049       1
 2 31.1149       1
 3 34.5249       1
 4 39.7249       1
 5 44.9249       1
 6 50.1299       1
```

Summary of column `gr` is as below:

```
summary(GR)
       gr            
 Min.   :-6.94     
 1st Qu.:10.71   
 Median :13.76   
 Mean   :18.99   
 3rd Qu.:20.70   
 Max.   :98.42   
 NA's   :55
```

Basic Histogram of the entire data for the `gr` is suitably created. For further analysis, it is required to identify each `wellseq` contributing in the histogram. The `ggplot()` script used is:

```
p2 <- ggplot() + theme_bw() + 
        geom_histogram(data=GR, na.rm= TRUE, mapping = aes(x=gr, fill=factor(GR$wellseq)), 
           bins = 10) + scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 100)) +
        labs(title=paste("Gamma Ray","Histogram", sep=" ")) +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Sequential Color in Histogram]
The resulting output has color - which is "sequential" and NOT the "qualitative" palette "Dark2".  I tried using the answer in "How to generate a number of most distinctive colors in R?" @ stackoverflow.com and created required colors.

```
Dcolor = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
DcolorR <- sample(Dcolor, 433, replace = F)
```

using `scale_colour_manual(values = DcolorR)`

gives the same histogram. Using `..count..` for `y` the histogram does show the boundaries for different `wellseq` but does not fill as needed.

```
p3 <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram(data=GR, na.rm= TRUE, mapping = aes(x=gr, y= ..count.., col = factor(GR$wellseq), bins = 10)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = DcolorR) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 100)) +
    labs(title=paste("Gamma Ray"," Frequency Histogram", sep=" ")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
fill = 1 # leads to blue colored staked histogram
```

[image: ..count.. creates discrete boundaries in the bars. Fill is single color]
I am trying to get a plot like attached. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: you need to use `fill=` not `col=` to control the fill color. Then change `scale_color_manual` to `scale_fill_manual`.Also, please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you set `aes(x=gr, fill=wellseq)` then you should get what you are looking for which is a grouping of the subsets of gr as defined by their membership in wellseq.

Look here.Previous simple version of a grouped histogram [R histogram with multiple populations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612805/r-histogram-with-multiple-populations)