# Try to do a histogram with a particularity in R

Tags: r, histogram

I really hope you will understad my problem beacause english is not my first language :)

I try to do a simple histogram of frequency. My data go someting like this :

```
    ID    Time    Censure
    1       70       1
    2       150      1 
    3       80       0
    4       100      1
    5       120      0
```

So, i want a histograme of the frequency of time but a want to have a separation for the censure ? Like a cumulative histogram ?

Very sorry if you don't understand !

Thank

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612805/r-histogram-with-multiple-populations?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes something like that but whit classe from my Time.